# How to format a date using preg_split

Tags: php, regex, timestamp

2011-03-30 17:47:31
So this is the date in my mysql database;

what do I do to do that?

I want it to look like 30/03/2011 | 17:47:31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the date with the format you want, by using the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function in your SQL query.

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT(datefield, '%d/%m/%Y | %H:%i:%s')` to be exact.

Answer (score 2):

```
date('d/m/Y | G:i:s', strtotime($theOriginalTime))
```

That should do what you need.

Comment: Wasteful - easier to do the conversion in MySQL and save the overhead of the strtotime() parsing.

Comment: Oh the age old debate begins again.  I'm not a fan of putting business logic in a database.  It's a personal preference.

Comment: True enough. Depends on how efficient the OP needs things to be. Pulling out a kajillion dates would suggest doing the date formatting in the database. Doing it once an hour makes the PHP overhead a bit easier to digest.

Comment: Now if we could only teach politicians to have polite conversations like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to use preg_split, just do:

```
date("d/m/Y | G:i:s", strtotime($timestamp));
```

Or fetch the unix timestamp from MySQL with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` and then do:

```
date("d/m/Y | G:i:s", $unix_timestamp);
```

Comment: Wasteful - easier to do the conversion in MySQL and save the php-side roundtrip through strtotime or the unix_timestamp conversion

Comment: I'd say both are valid approaches, depending on your design pattern. If for instance the database interaction code and the formatting code are separate, doing the formatting in PHP is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily solved with a regex. Here is a tested PHP function which reformats any and all such dates in a given text string:

```php
function convert_dates($text) {
    // Convert 2011-03-30 17:47:31 to 30/03/2011 | 17:47:31
    $re = '/# Match components of a YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS date.
        \b                     # Begin on word boundary
        (\d{4})-               # $1: Year.
        (\d{2})-               # $2: Month.
        (\d{2})[ ]             # $3: Day.
        (\d{2}):               # $4: Hour.
        (\d{2}):               # $5: Minute.
        (\d{2})                # $6: Second.
        \b                     # End on word boundary.
        /Sx';
    $replace = '$3/$2/$1 | $4:$5:$6';
    return preg_replace($re, $replace, $text);
}
```